# How to use Ignite visor CLI with SSL?

Tags: ssl, caching, ignite

All,
I have Apache Ignite running on a windows server on SSL mode. I would like to use Visor CLI to connect to the cluster. How do I pass the SSL related information while executing ignitevisorcmd.bat?

Currently I am executing as below and it works fine when SSL is not enabled.
IGNITE_HOME/bin/ignitevisorcmd.bat

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To enable SSL for Visor CLI it's required to configure the `sslContextFactory` property in the XML configuration file, which is used to establish the connection to the cluster, as shown below:

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    ...
    <property name="sslContextFactory">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.ssl.SslContextFactory">
            <property name="keyStoreFilePath" value="keystore/node.jks"/>
            <property name="keyStorePassword" value="123456"/>
            <property name="trustStoreFilePath" value="keystore/trust.jks"/>
            <property name="trustStorePassword" value="123456"/>
            <property name="protocol" value="TLSv1.3"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Basically, Visor CLI starts a client node under the hood, which means that the [SSL/TLS for Nodes](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/security/ssl-tls#ssltls-for-nodes) documentation section can be used for its configuration.

Also, you can find additional details in the security guide [here](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/tutorials/security/ssl-guide#visor-cli).